# Using Green's Theorem to find area

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

[image: Use a line integral on the boundary to find the area]

Hi,

I'm little confused to use green's theorem for the area with using C1 and C2 curves. I tried to find the area by using polar coordinates but I ended up with a diverging integral. I calculated the line integrals for each curve and added them up and got ${\pi}/4-3/2$ which is negative.

I basically used$\int ydx$ on C1 and C2  Can anyone help me how I can solve this?

edit: I used $ 1/2\int xdy-ydx$ for C1 and C2 and got ${\pi}/4-1/2$ which I suppose it's the right answer.

thanks

Comment: I think there is some calculation mistake made...the area should be $\pi/4-1/2$, without even using integration.